# Como não selecionar registros que estejam dentro de uma data?

Tags: mysql, select, data

Tenho uma tabela em MySQL com apartamento, assim:

```
id |   nome   | data_ja_locado
1  | ap teste | 09/08/2015, 10/08/2015, 11/08/2015
```

Aí quando o usuário faz uma busca ele quer achar apartamentos que estejam disponíveis dentro de um espaço de tempo. Se ele colocar como CHECKIN 10/08/2015 e como CHECKOUT 11/08/2015 não era para aparecer o "ap teste" do exemplo acima.

Como fazer essa consulta?

Tentei assim:

```
SELECT * FROM apartamento WHERE data_locado NOT BETWEEN '10/08/2015' AND '11/08/2015'
```

Mas ele lista o apartamento mesmo assim, alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

Comment: Tens as datas separadas por virgulas no campo `data_ja_locado`?

Comment: Não estou a ver uma boa forma de fazer isso...

Comment: @JorgeB. isso mesmo!

Comment: Isso é terrível!

Comment: Imagino que eu teria que saber todas as datas que tem dentro do checkin e checkout e ver se existe alguma dessa data no campo data_ja_locado, mas não sei como

Comment: Eu sei bem o que queres fazer, o problema é que o campo `data_ja_locado` não é uma data é uma string com datas, não há forma de fazer assim uma pesquisa, que eu saiba. Vais ter de ir buscar todas as datas e tratar disso no teu PHP.

Comment: @JorgeB. e qual a forma correta?

Comment: A forma correta era teres uma tabela `apartamento_datas` onde constassem todas as datas por apartamento. Por exemplo, com os campos `id | id_apartamento | data_ocupacao`.

Comment: A data tem que estar no formato americano: 2015-08-10 AND 2015-08-11 e ser um campo do tipo DATE, caso vc esteja usando um campo VARCHAR, ou TEXT, você precisa corrigir isso.

Comment: Você está fazendo isso errado, em vez de colocar as datas num único campo separado por vírgula. Coloque elas numa tabela separada, em formato americano e chame elas através de uma chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você poderia contornar o problema:
Crie uma tabela auxiliar com as datas de locação do apartamento chamada **datas_locacao**. Depois ao invés de colocar as data num único campo, consulte o dado pela id do apartamento, e traga consigo as datas relacionando a esta tabela:

```
+------------------------------------+
| id_data | id_apto | data_ja_locado |
+------------------------------------+
|    1    |    1    |  2015-08-09    |
+------------------------------------+
|    2    |    1    |  2015-08-10    |
+------------------------------------+
|    3    |    1    |  2015-08-11    |
+------------------------------------+
|    4    |    1    |  2015-08-12    |
+------------------------------------+
|    5    |    1    |  2015-09-01    |
+------------------------------------+
|    6    |    1    |  2015-09-02    |
+------------------------------------+
```

Primeiro você irá trazer a lista de apartamentos que não fazem parte da sua consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT apt.* FROM apartamento apt
        INNER JOIN datas_locacao loc
        ON(loc.id_apto=apt.id_apto)
        WHERE loc.data_ja_locado 
        NOT BETWEEN '2015-08-09' AND '2015-08-11' ";
```

Onde a consulta exibirá os demais resultados, como no exemplo:

```
$aptos = array(
              0 => array(
                        'id_apto' => 1,
                        'nome'=> 'ap teste'
                        )
             );
```

Feito isso, agora dentro do **foreach**, faça uma segunda consulta trazendo todas as datas para esta consulta:

```
$sql_datas = "SELECT id_data,
                     DATE_FORMAT(data_ja_locado,'%d-%m-%Y') as data_loc
              FROM   datas_locacao
              WHERE  id_apto = '$id_apto' and data_ja_locado 
              NOT    BETWEEN '2015-08-09' AND '2015-08-11' 
              ORDER  BY data_ja_locado ASC ";
```

Esta consulta traria o seguinte resultado:

```
+-------------------------+
| id_data |   data_loc    |
+-------------------------+
|    4    |  12/08/2015   |
+-------------------------+
|    5    |  01/09/2015   |
+-------------------------+
|    6    |  02/09/2015   |
+-------------------------+
```

Onde a consulta exibirá os demais resultados, como no exemplo:

```
$datas_locacao['id_apto']['1'] = array(
                                0 => array(
                                      'id_data' => 4,
                                      'data_loc'=> '12/08/2015'
                                     ),
                                1 => array(
                                      'id_data' => 2,
                                      'data_loc'=> '01/09/2015'
                                     ),
                                2 => array( 
                                      'id_data' => 3,
                                      'data_loc'=> '02/09/2015'
                                     )
                               );
```

Feito isso basta juntar e exibir os resultados:

```
foreach ($aptos as $key => $apto) {
          $datas = array();
          foreach ($datas_locacao[$key][$apto['id_apto']] as $data) {
              $datas[] =  $data['data_loc'];         
          }
   echo "<b>Apto: <b/>" . $apto['nome'];
   echo "<b>Período(s) de locação:<b/>" . implode(" - ", $datas)    
}
```

Saída:

> **Apto:** ap teste
>   **Período(s) de locação:** 12/08/2015 - 01/09/2015 - 02/09/2015

Comment: É isso, me salvou!

Eu tive que usar um banco de dados espelhado porque não podia alterar o banco do cliente, mas deu certo!